# Using MS Graph API is it possible to just list the email attachments without downloading the its content?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, outlook-graph-api

We're using MS Graph API to get the list of emails from an Outlook 365 mailbox. We have a requirement to list the attachments in every email.

When using the List Attachments endpoint of the Graph API, the `contentBytes` attribute value in the response contains the entire Base64 encoded attachment content. This increases the response size significantly. We have no need to access or store the attachment content.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-list-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example

Is there a way in MS Graph API to just get the attachment file name(s) and IDs for one or more email messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same `/attachments` endpoint and get only the id and name of attachment using the [$select query parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#select-parameter).

Simply use the query

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{messageid}/attachments?$select=id,name`

**Result:**

[image]

You can always test graph calls in [Graph Explore](https://aka.ms/ge).

Comment: Thank you, Shiva! This works like a charm! I'm using the Python [O365](https://github.com/O365/python-o365/blob/master/O365/utils/attachment.py) library. Unfortunately, it doesn't provide a way to specify the select parameters out-of-the-box. I'll extend the BaseAttachment class to do that.

Comment: Glad to here that it helped you :)-